# Does newton's method require only the second order partial deriatives of the same variables, or all elements of the Hessian matrix?

Tags: gradient-descent, newton-raphson, hessian-matrix

**Does Newton's method in optimization require the computation of only the second order partial deriatives of single variables, or all elements of the Hessian matrix?**

From [Newton's method in optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization), Newton's method performs the iteration
$${\displaystyle x_{k+1}=x_{k}+t=x_{k}-{\frac {f'(x_{k})}{f''(x_{k})}}.}$$
So it seems the Newton method's update only requires first and second order gradients. This is the case of XGBoost in Machine Learning:

- https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3227
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XGBoost#The_algorithm

[image]

But some sources I read tell that the Newton method requires Hessian Matrix:

[https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/hessian-matrix#:~:text=For%20us%20to%20implement%20the,it%20has%20to%20be%20updated](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/hessian-matrix#:%7E:text=For%20us%20to%20implement%20the,it%20has%20to%20be%20updated)

But Hessian Matrix contains second order partial derivatives of two different variables in the non-diagonal elements:
$${\displaystyle \mathbf {H} _{f}={\begin{bmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}^{2}}}&{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\,\partial x_{2}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1}\,\partial x_{n}}}\\[2.2ex]{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\,\partial x_{1}}}&{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}^{2}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{2}\,\partial x_{n}}}\\[2.2ex]\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\[2.2ex]{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{n}\,\partial x_{1}}}&{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{n}\,\partial x_{2}}}&\cdots &{\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{n}^{2}}}\end{bmatrix}},}$$

So is the second order partial derivatives of the same variables (or the **diagonal elements of Hessian Matrix** alone) enough for Newton's method? Are the rest upper/lower triangular elements of Hessian matrix used anywhere in the Newton method as well, e.g., $\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1} \partial x_{2}}$?

Comment: The first formula you give is for single variables. With more than one variable, the whole Hessian is needed (to be more precise, the inverse of the Hessian is used in place of the reciprocal of $f''$) -- see the section on higher dimensions in your first link.

Comment: @JKL Thanks for your comment. When we have a multivariable function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, isn't it that $f''(x_1)$, $f''(x_2)$, $f''(x_3)$ are just three different scalar values (the second order derivatives of each variable)? Where is the roles of the Hessian Matrix's upper/lower triangular elements such as $\dfrac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{1} \partial x_{2}}$ here in the Newton method's update?

Comment: I think I get it now --- about where the Hessian matrix comes from .... It comes from the Second-degree Taylor Polynomial of a function of multi variables. For the case of XGBoost or Gradient Boosting, since it goes with a (loss) function of a single variable $\hat y$ if I'm understanding it correctly, `"it computes the second partial derivative of the (element-wise) loss function with respect to the predicted label"` (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3227) instead of Hessian matrix.